# Previewing FixedDocument in DocumentViewer looks ok, printing it always prints the first page

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, fixeddocument

I'm creating a `FixedDocument` by adding `FixedPages` to `PageContents`, then adding them to the `FixedDocument` somehow like this

```
FixedDocument fd = new FixedDocument();
// add FixedPages in PageContent to fd
```

Printing them with a `PrintDialog`, like this

```
pdialog.PrintDocument(fd.DocumentPaginator, "Test");
```

results in the correct number of pages. However, every page printed - e.g. to a PDF - is the content of the first page.

I tried testing the `ImageSources` I add to the `FixedPages`, those seem correct. I also tested the final `FixedDocument` with a `DocumentViewer` like so

```
Window wnd = new Window();
DocumentViewer viewer = new DocumentViewer();
viewer.Document = fd;
wnd.Content = viewer;
try
{
    wnd.Show();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

This strangely shows the correct output I would expect. What's even stranger is that I get an `IOException` after `wnd.Show();` (which is why I surrounded it with a try/catch). Even with the try catch I can only view it maybe 1-2 seconds before the same `IOException` thrown by my `MainWindow`. Something like "Wrong username or password" - which doesn't make sense, since the images I'm trying to print are local ones.

Putting the `DocumentViewer` aside, my problem with the `Print()` method only printing the first page n times (n being the number of actual pages it should be) still persists, just thought that the exception in the `DocumentViewer` may give someone an idea of an underlying problem.

This might be a possible duplicate of [FixedDocument always print first page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137665/fixeddocument-always-print-first-page) - however he doesn't mention problems with `DocumentViewer` and the question remains unanswered.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I might be able to help debug this if you can provide a reproducible example for me to test.

Comment: @Keith Stein thanks for the reply, but at least I found the underlying problem (see my answer below), just not why it's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar issue, printing labels in a FixedDocument from a List of Data, that contains a List Of Image Sources (User Photo), and also dynamically creates a QRCode image from an integer for the users id.

The format for the image is created from a custom UserControl that I used to position The Text fields and images for each label.  When I viewed the created document in the DocumentViewer control, it displayed perfectly. Correct photo image, correct QRCode image for each label. However, when I printed the document (or saved to PDF file  or XPS File), Ever Label had only the first image in both the Photo and QRCode image positions on the label.

When I came across this post, I though that I would try saving then reloading the images as suggested, and this worked!! However the IO overhead for 30 labels per page, and many pages of labels meant that this wasn't a very useful workaround! I

Then found that simply converting the ImageSource to a ByteArray, and then back again, before adding to the FixedDocument worked also, but without the added IO overhead. Not massively elegant, but has been a real headache for me for a week now!!

Here is a snippet of code from the main body of the method that builds the labels:

```
var qr = GetQRCodeImage(playerId);  // Gets ImageSource
var ph = LoadImage(data[dataIndex].Photo); // Gets ImageSource
var qrCode = FixDocumentCacheImageBugFix(qr); // Gets ImageSource
if (ph != null) {
    var photo = FixDocumentCacheImageBugFix(ph);
    label = new AveryBarcodeLabel(line1, line2, line3, qrCode, photo); // Calls constructor to instantiate new Label with new ImageSources
}
else {
    label = new AveryBarcodeLabel(line1, line2, line3, qrCode); // Calls constructor to instantiate new Label with new ImageSources (where photo is null)
}
```

and here are the methods I used to "Fix" the Images

```
public static ImageSource FixDocumentCacheImageBugFix(ImageSource image) {
    var bytes = ImageSourceToBytes(image);
    return ByteToImage(bytes);
}
public static ImageSource ByteToImage(byte[] imageData) {
    var biImg = new BitmapImage();
    var ms = new MemoryStream(imageData);
    biImg.BeginInit();
    biImg.StreamSource = ms;
    biImg.EndInit();
    
    ImageSource imgSrc = biImg;

    return imgSrc;
}
public static byte[] ImageSourceToBytes(ImageSource imageSource) {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    var bitmapSource = imageSource as BitmapSource;

    if (bitmapSource != null) {
        var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
        
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
                encoder.Save(stream);
                bytes = stream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return bytes;
   }
```

Comment: Glad that my "solution" lead you to a more elegant way of solving this. Tried it with the ByteArray conversion, worked for me too, thanks! I can't shake my head around the idea that there really isn't a better solution to this, but hey, it's way better than my "temp file" way :)

Answer (score 0):

So, this isn't really the answer to **why** it happened, but I found at least the culprit: my image.

I'm loading a multipage LZW-compressed TIFF like so:

```
TiffBitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
foreach (ImageSource frame in encoder.Frames)
{
    frame.Freeze();
    Images.Add(frame);
}
```

where `Images` is a collection of `ImageSource`. They display fine in the application, I can also save them again using a `TiffBitmapEncoder`, but printing them using WPF ends up with the in the question mentioned problem as well as - when using a `DocumentViewer` - an exception telling me about 'wrong username or password', which doesn't make sense.

The way I found out the image to be the problem was temporarily saving the individual `ImageSources` of the TIFF using a `PngBitmapEncoder` and immediately reloading the pages from the separate files with the same encoder into the same slot in my `Images` collection.

Since this works without any issues (no username/password exception in my `DocumentViewer` **and** my printing working correctly) I have to assume that he doesn't like something about the TIFF format.

This doesn't answer my underlying question of **why** it didn't work, but since this is at least a workaround that works, I'll just put that here and don't check the 'answered' mark just yet.

Maybe someone knows why my TIFF `ImageSource` produced those strange results?